# How do I write a function that will read an XElement.Value and convert it to the specified type in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this file for my settings.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <!--Settings document for System Gazatter-->
   <Settings>
      <OutputState>2</OutputState>
      <SystemPrefix>XCL</SystemPrefix>
      <MaxNumSystems>2147483647</MaxNumSystems>
      <OpenCluster>0</OpenCluster>
      <GardenWorld>False</GardenWorld>
      <StellarVariance>False</StellarVariance>
      <StellarMassOverride allow="True">
        <MinStellarMass>1.00</MinStellarMass>
        <MaxStellarMass>2</MaxStellarMass>
      </StellarMassOverride>
      <NumberOfStarsOverride allow="False">1</NumberOfStarsOverride>
    </Settings>
```

I want to write a function that is something like

```
public static T getSettingElementValue(XDocument settings, string elementName) {
  return (T)(settingDoc.Element("Settings")
     .Select(x=>x.Element(elementName))
     .First()
     .Value);
}
```

Now, I know this won't work. (It's also missing any checks on calls.) Is there some way to do this? Or should I fall back to something like.

```
public static string getSettingElementStringValue(...)
public static string getSettingElementDoubleValue(...)
```

Comment: If you want typed access, you could consider creating a class for it and deserialize the file into an object.

Comment: Yeah I would just use a different approach entirely. I don't know what your options are but I also wouldn't use XML for that data. Also, you could put this stuff in the appconfig and it would get parsed for you. Just a few ideas. Of course you may have some constraints preventing you from taking any of that advice, if not I'd drop this file altogether.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal As I said below, I'm not entirely sure XML is the best thing. It's just the easiest I could think of.

Comment: If I could implement that anyway I chose I would probably make the file json and use json.NET to deserialize into a settings class. It's quick and easy to implement, requires the developer to implement no logic, and offers complete type safety. If I was really looking for a quick and dirty implementation I would use key-value new line delimited pairs and read them into a dictionary of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public static T getSettingElementValue<T>(XDocument settings, string elementName) {
  return (T)Convert.ChangeType(settings.Element("Settings").Element(elementName).Value, typeof(T));     
}

void Main()
{
    var xml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\abc\blah.xml");

    Console.WriteLine(getSettingElementValue<bool>(xml, "GardenWorld"));
}
```

...but I would still follow the advice of *not* having your data like this and just using the App.config or something easier. This'll also only work if `T` implements `IConvertible`, so you should probably add that type constraint on `T`.

Comment: And what if you typed `SystemPrefix` (string) rather than `GardenWorld` accidentally? `InvalidCastException` I guess...

Comment: Conversion error, so you have to be fairly vigilant in making sure your types match up with the type of the value you're trying to get, which is fairly annoying. At the very least, it won't fail silently.

Comment: So you miss the Generics concept I think.

Comment: Well. I wouldn't mind having a different idea than using a XDocument. It's just I needed some way to persist settings across file -> program main -> options window -> program and then save. I wanted something like an .ini but .NET seems to want to push you towards XML. That does appear to answer the question though.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as answered (the green checkmark). I suggest you take a look at App.config or a simple config file parser/writer (there are plenty of libraries for it).

Answer (score 0):

You already have an answer, but I wrote an XML library (See [here](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/blob/master/XElementExtensions.cs#L228)) a while back that does this in it with the following:

```
XElement settings = XElement.Load(file); // or .Parse(string)
bool flag = settings.Get("GardenWorld", false); // false is a default and does the generic type for you
```

One of the ways it does it is similar to the answer, but it also uses other methods if they don't work, such as trying for a `TryParse(string)` on the type and checking to see if the type has a string constructor.